# How to fix ServerStack RabbitMQ fanout exchange test that fails, without rewriting the whole test

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

I'm running all the ServiceStack tests for RabbitMQ and for the life of me I couldn't get this one "Publishing_message_to_fanout_exchange_publishes_to_all_queues" to pass. After a bit of digging and reading I've found that:

1. The name of the test should be changed to Topic, instead of fanout (The ServiceStack framework built in functionality doesn't provide for it).
2. There is no need for RegisterQueue, RegisterTopic, and RegisterDlq static methods in the test file, you should use the RabbitMqExtensions.
3. These two statements below actually do the same thing in essence, bind a queue to an exchange (topic) AND provide for a routing key, BUT the routing keys are different so only one of the queues gets a message published to it, so the test always fails.

   ```
   RegisterTopic(channel, QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.Out);

   RegisterQueue(channel, QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.In, exchange: ExchangeTopic);
   ```

I'm hoping someone could enlighten me as to whether or not this test ever passed.

Thank you, Stephen

Comment: Opening an issue on GitHub would have been preferable to this post, except I can't seem to find the issues dialog.

Comment: FYI ServiceStack Issues is at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test was refactored incorrectly, it used to use a `fanout` exchange as seen in [its commit history](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/eaa936ebf8f930353e70242d812f99e3eafc3bfb/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Messaging/RabbitMqTests.cs#L146-L172).

I've [just changed it](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/c200355d14d7b657923ff8e893e597bcc7cd79a1) to use a fanout exchange as seen in:

```
[Test]
public void Publishing_message_to_fanout_exchange_publishes_to_all_queues()
{
    using (IConnection connection = mqFactory.CreateConnection())
    using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.RegisterFanoutExchange(ExchangeFanout);

        RegisterQueue(channel, QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.In, exchange: ExchangeFanout);
        RegisterQueue(channel, QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.Priority, exchange: ExchangeFanout);

        byte[] payload = new HelloRabbit { Name = "World!" }.ToJson().ToUtf8Bytes();
        var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        props.SetPersistent(true);

        channel.BasicPublish(ExchangeFanout, QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.In, props, payload);

        var basicGetMsg = channel.BasicGet(QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.In, noAck: true);
        Assert.That(basicGetMsg, Is.Not.Null);

        basicGetMsg = channel.BasicGet(QueueNames<HelloRabbit>.Priority, noAck: true);
        Assert.That(basicGetMsg, Is.Not.Null);
    }
}
```

Comment: In hindsight I should have asked for a new test that covers Topic exchange with the same parameters as this one.

Comment: Please add the fanout exchange to the string array at this line https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c200355d14d7b657923ff8e893e597bcc7cd79a1/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Messaging/RabbitMqTests.cs#L355

Comment: @StephenPatten good call [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/c1e1a79f2b9df8dd32aaeb4408c86acef32d0f72) although this would've been the perfect opportunity for a first pull request :)